# Get the time of the day with most active users

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to solve the next challenge:

We have table `sessions` with `user_id`, user `login_time` and `logout_time`. Something like this, a million records in one day:

| id | user_id | login_time | logout_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 546 | 2023-05-10 09:30:33 | 2023-05-10 09:52:33 |
| 2 | 245 | 2023-05-10 01:00:56 | 2023-05-10 01:37:56 |
| 3 | 546 | 2023-05-10 19:22:25 | NULL |

(logout time can be null if the session is still active)

We need to find at what time the system had the most logged-in users.

The best solution I could come up with:

```
SELECT minutes::timestamp, COUNT(user_id) as active_users
FROM generate_series(timestamp '2023-05-10 00:00:00', timestamp '2023-05-10 23:59:59', interval '10 min') t(minutes)
INNER JOIN sessions as s
    on minutes between s.login_time and (CASE
    WHEN logout_time IS NULL THEN '2023-05-10 23:59:59'
    ELSE logout_time
    END)
GROUP BY minutes
ORDER BY active_users DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

But it has serious flaws:

1. It takes about 35 seconds to complete
2. It works with periods of 10 minutes - I would like to increase the precision to the minute, or maybe even the second, if it's possible to get in 5-10 seconds.
3. I'm not all sure that I'm moving in the right direction :)

Please, help me to optimize query or throw at me some examples of queries that solves similar tasks.

Comment: I would generate a series of dates between the min and max date range in whatever increment you require, second, minute etc, then join this to your table where the dates are in the range of login/out time then aggregate and count, which looks to be basically what you have done - I would not use *between* though use > <=. Performance will depend on having a suitable index on the date columns.

Comment: Thank you! What type of index you can recommend to put on the date columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your query, you could *try* the following index:

```
create index idx_sessions_range
on sessions (login_time, logout_time desc);
```

Also, I wonder if it might be more efficient to unpivot the logins/logouts - so we don’t need to use `generate_series` and a `join`. It also has the upshot of giving you the exact point in time when the max users count was reached:

```
select *
from (
    select x.ts, 
        sum(sum(x.cnt)) over(order by x.ts) cnt_active_users
    from sessions s
    cross join lateral ( 
        values
            (s.login_time,   1), 
            (s.logout_time, -1)
    ) x(ts, cnt)
    where s.login_time < date '2023-05-11'
        and (s.logout_time >= date '2023-05-10' or s.logout_time is null)
    group by x.ts
) x
where ts >= date '2023-05-10' and ts < date '2023-05-11'
order by cnt_active_users desc, ts
limit 1
```

The subquery filters on sessions that overlap the search period, unpivots and computes the count of active users at each point in time. The outer query is there to filter out data points that are out of the search window.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution works just perfectly. It queries the table with 1.7 M records in just 7 seconds in dockerized postgres container on mac m1. Seems that index doesn't provide any boost, but I think it's overwhelming result. Now I need to understand all this magic :) 

Thanks again!